# C# Nested classes

Tags: c#, class, nested

I am trying to create a few nested classes within my main class.

```
public class MyPlayer : Player
{

    public bool TargetEnemy()
    {
        return true;

    }

    public class Movement
    {
        public uint aInt = 1;

        public TurnLeft()
        {

        }
    }

    public class ActionBar
    {

    }
}
```

I have many different classes so that I would be able to access the MyPlayer class through out the code without passing it to all them I just created a static class that holds the variable for it. I am able to access the MyPlayer->Movement using Main.Units.MyPlayer.Movement but this is not linked to the MyPlayer instance I have defined in the static class.

I want to be able to do MyPlayer->Movement->TurnLeft() for example. How would I achieve this? Thanks for your answers.

Comment: `multiple-inheritance` is a totally different thing (and doesn't exist in`.Net`) I removed that tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be mistaking the concept of class nesting with class composition. In order to have a `Movement` instance within your `Player` class, you can define a private field `movement` and a public property `Movement` to access it.

```
public class Player
{        
    public bool TargetEnemy()
    {
        return true;            
    }

    private Movement movement = new Movement();

    public Movement Movement
    {
        get { return movement; }
        set { movement = value; }
    }
}

public class Movement
{
    public uint aInt = 1;

    public TurnLeft()
    {

    }
}

public class ActionBar
{

}
```

Then, you may create an instance of your `Player` class and access its contained `Movement`:

```
Player myPlayer = new Player();
myPlayer.Movement.TurnLeft();
```

Comment: Since the `Movement` class seems to be mutable, I would remove the setter of the `Movement` property.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Good point, but I can’t infer enough from the class design to determine whether it _should_ be mutable. My suspicion is that it shouldn’t, and that `TurnLeft` should actually be replaced by some polymorphic `Move` method (to be overridden by derived classes for specific kinds of movements).

Answer (score 0):

Then `MyPlayer` should have a reference to a `Movement` instance.

```
public class MyPlayer : Player
{
    public static Movement movement = new Movement();
    ...
}
```